# Auth Provider for Trello?

Tags: api, oauth2, authentication, httprequest, namedcredentials

I've spent too many hours today trying to set up an Auth Provider + Named Credential for Trello's auth flow... I guess my question is, for those who have dealt with Auth Providers in SFDC, is this even possible?

Docs: https://developers.trello.com/page/authorization

I just want to avoid hard coding tokens...

**Edit for more context:**

My basic question is, given the documentation above, is that supported by Salesforce's Auth Provider + Named Credential features?

I have tried setting up an Auth Provider using OpenID Connect, however it doesn't format the URL correctly and it cannot obtain the token.

I can't simply store the key & token in a Password auth Named Cred and use merge fields because Trello's API requires them to be passed as part of the endpoint (merge fields are not available there).

I'm not a dev by trade and auth is definitely not my forte... If I can't get the auth flow to work, how would I implement the "Basic OAuth" (1.0) option at the end of their documentation? (I tried looking at the example but...I don't know how to translate that to Apex)

Comment: Whats your question? are you stuck anywhere? is it not working?

Comment: @RedDevil I've updated for more context

Comment: Since Trello doesn't support a modern authorization scheme (oAuth 1.0 is ancient and full of issues), this requires development. Hire a dev.

Comment: @identigral Thanks, looping back to the question though, would SFDC Auth Provider + Named Credential be an option? If so, would it require a custom Auth Provider Plug-in?

Comment: You want Named Credential + custom code. Auth Provider won't help you here.

Comment: Also, have a look at Trello's built-in SF integration: https://help.trello.com/article/1055-using-the-salesforce-power-up